# How to copy file to path that contains ampersand '&' using Python's shutil?

Tags: python, shutil

I am complete newbie in Python and have to modify existing Python script. The script copies file to other path like following:

`err=shutil.copyfile(src, dst)`

This works unless `dst` contains character like `&`:

`dst = "Y:\R&D\myfile.txt"`

In this case I get windows error popup that says

```
Open file or Read file error
Y:\R
```

I tried to escape & using back slash, double back slash and wrapping the string with additional quotes: `dst = "\"Y:\R&D\myfile.txt\""`.
Nothing works in last case I get "invalid path" error message from `shutil`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Rename the directory to something different first. And you'll avoid many more problems in the future.

Comment: @eumiro, thanks for advice. But this is not the solution. This is work-around. I do have to copy file to directory that is called `R&D`

Comment: Please include the full stack trace, and state the version of Python and the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that ampersand is supported on most platforms. You will likely have to make a call to a windows specific program. I suggest robocopy since its really good at copying files. If it's not included in your version of windows, you can find it in the windows server administrator toolkit for 2003.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I change all the `\` in the filepaths to `/` (in both `src` and `dst` strings). Yes, I know you're using Windows, but filepaths always seem to be less fussy in Python if you use `/`, even in Windows.

Also, it looks like you're copying to a network drive. Do you get the same problem copying to `c:\R&D\`?

What flavor of Windows are you using? `shutil.copyfile()` works fine for me with `&` in directory names, in both src and dst paths, in both local and network drives on XP -- as long as I use `/` in place of `\`.

Comment: Thanks, @alan. I did mistake when writing the question. Really I tried both `\\` and `/`. My problem is not slash but ampersand

Comment: It's strange because I have no problem here copying files to/from directories with ampersands. What is your `Y:` drive mapped to? I wonder if that is the problem. Do you have the same problem copying to `C:`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the "\" with "\ \", this command must work (for example):

```
 shutil.copyfile("Y:\\R&D\\myfile.txt", "C:\\TMP")
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution, signify to python that the string is raw and not to escape it or modify it in any way:

```
import shutil

src = r"c:\r&d\file.txt"
dst = r"c:\r&d\file2.txt"

err=shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few ways to make it work on windows:

- Approach 1: (already explained)

  > `import shutil; shutil.copy(src,dest)`
  >   
  > as long as src/dest are using `r'c:\r&d\file'` string format. It also works with forward "/" slashes as well.
- Approach 2: Notice use of double quotes instead of single quotes on windows.

  > `src = r'c:\r & d\src_file'`
  >
  > `os.system('copy "{}" "{}"'.format(src,dest))
  >           1 file(s) copied`
- Last resort:

  > `with open(dest, 'wb') as f: 
  >         f.write(open(src,'rb').read())`

Unlike `os.system`, this preferred implementation `subprocess.call` could not work with any quoting approach on windows. I always get `The specified path is invalid.` Did not try on unix.